# Ergodic Process: Does it visit all state?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

I read in [this](http://vserver1.cscs.lsa.umich.edu/~crshalizi/notabene/ergodic-theory.html) article:

" Ludwig Boltzmann, coined "ergodic" as the name for a stronger but related property: starting from a random point in state space, orbits will typically pass through every point in state space. It is easy to show (with set theory) that this isn't doable,..."

Could someone please explain how this can be proved. I have seen [other](http://vivonets.ece.ucsb.edu/ChoudhuryGibson_ITW07.pdf) articles that define that an ergodic process will go to every state with some probability.

Second part of my question is, what is the relationship between stationary process and an ergodic process?

Comment: There's no relationship between stationary and ergodic.  They are different attributes of processes.  If a process has both attributes, you can prove a lot of theorems about the process.

Comment: @John If a process $X(t)$is non-stationary then the ensemble average can change with time. E.g. $EX(t))\neq EX(t+s)$ then how can this process be ergodic ? Since as I know if process is ergodic then time average should equal ensemble average, but now we don't have one ensemble average. So it seems like there is a dependency between ergodic process and stationary process.

Comment: WRT Q2: e.g. Second order stationarity assumes that the first 2 moments (mean and covariance) are independent of location (or time); wherever you are you'll get the same mean, whichever way you look you'll get the same covariance (space/time distance being equal). Full stationarity would assume stationarity of all moments. WRT ergodic processes i believe it may be an assumption. An ergodic process assumes that the statistical properties can be deduced from one realization. I say assumption b/c you often can't access more than one realization in real life (check wikipedia).

Comment: @triomphe Silly example, $X(t) = B(t) + e^{-t}$ where $B(t)$ is a brownian motion, is ergodic, but not stationary.

Comment: What is the definition of ergodicity you are talking about ? Is it ergodicity of a measure-preserving transformation ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ergodic in mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process. I don't know about measure-preserving transformations. Thanks

Comment: @triomphe Ok, but from your quote by Boltzmann *"orbits will typically pass through every point in state space"* I suspect he's talking about a measure-preserving transformation (a dynamical system).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Sorry, I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand that.

Comment: @triomphe Actually this should be equivalent for a discrete-time stationary process. Are you interested in discrete or continuous time ?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the set of states with a given energy is a manifold of dimension $>1$.  Typically, the orbits are differentiable functions of time.  Then one shows **with topology** (not with set theory) that the orbit is not equal to the whole manifold.

If you drop the condition of differentiability, then there are "space-filling" curves, so the orbit can, indeed, be everything.

Comment: Dear down voters, could you please explain the reasons to do so?